# ¿Como se puede convertir un MediaFile en stream? C#

Tags: c#

Estoy sacando una foto con xamarin y guardandolo en una carpeta temporal en el celular:

```
var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
            new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                    SaveToAlbum = true
            });
```

Ahora quiero guardarlo en una carpeta de mi pc local y para eso, por lo que entendí, necesito convertir la foto (Que es un MediaFile) en un Stream. Alguna ayuda de cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más rápido que se me ocurrió fue convertir el `MediaFile` en `byte[]` y el `byte[]` en `Stream`.

```
private byte[] ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(MediaFile file)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

 Stream newStream = new MemoryStream(imageToByte);
```